# Помогите с убиранием ободки у элемента label

Tags: html, css

При клике по элементу `label` появляется обоводка, `outline: none` и `border: none`, также пробовала давать им приоритет `!important` не помогло:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте ваш html-код, чтобы здесь можно было воспроизвести вашу проблему и найти ей решение.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш [mcve] вместе с html и css, иначе можно только догадываться, что у вас там

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего обводка появляется на `:focus`, `:active`, посмотрите еще на `:focus:active`.

!Но! С точки зрения UX, убирать обводку на фокус и актив не лучшее решение. В наши дни, особенно, когда бОльшее количество трафика мобильные устройства нужно показать пользователю, куда он кликнул. Если обводка не подходит дизайну, то предпочтительнее сменить ее цвет, добавить тень, но показать это событие.

Comment: Абсолютно согласен, и всё же постоянно все её убирают=)

Comment: @Arthur я предлагаю не стесняться), и делать актив и фокус самостоятельно, полупрозрачным, приглушенным одним из ведущих цветов макета, и цвет выделения прописывать. Это мелочи, которые делают верстку качественно лучше, 95% случаев об этом просто не думали, и не будут просить убрать. Но когда выделение идет вразрез с цветовой гаммой макета, то конечно, режет глаз, и заказчик может по незнанию попросить убрать это безобразие.